# MongoDB query to get data with OR operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've a db model called `Event`.

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  action: String,
  description: String,
  reference: {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    refType: String,
  },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Some records in the db are

```
action | description | refType
------------------------------------
Click  | Breakfast   | TmdSuggested
------------------------------------
Click  | Breakfast   | TmdMeatType
------------------------------------
Click  | Lunch       | TmdSuggested
------------------------------------
Click  | Lunch       | TmdMeatType
------------------------------------
```

Among these records I want to filter record only have these combinations.

```
action | description | refType
------------------------------------
Click  | Breakfast   | TmdSuggested
------------------------------------
Click  | Breakfast   | TmdMeatType
------------------------------------
Click  | Lunch       | TmdMeatType
------------------------------------
```

What I've done upto now is

```
{
                $match: {
                    action: 'Click',
                    $or: [
                        { description: 'Breakfast', reference: { refType: 'TmdSuggested' } },
                        { description: 'Breakfast', reference: { refType: 'TmdMeatType' } },
                        { description: 'Lunch', reference: { refType: 'TmdMeatType' } }
                    ]
                }
},
```

This doesn't give me an error. But this seems not working. No data is returning.
What's wrong in my code.

How do I achieve this using mongo db mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you query object's elements in MongoDB, I think this should work

```
$match: {
    action: "Click",
    $or: [
      {
        description: "Breakfast",
        "reference.refType": "TmdSuggested"
      },
      {
        description: "Breakfast",
        "reference.refType": "TmdMeatType"
      },
      {
        description: "Lunch",
        "reference.refType": "TmdMeatType"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can filter subitem with `reference.refType`.

```
{ $match: {
      action: 'Click',
      $or: [ { description: 'Breakfast', "reference.refType": 'TmdSuggested' },
             { description: 'Breakfast', "reference.refType": 'TmdMeatType' },
             { description: 'Lunch', "reference.refType": 'TmdMeatType' } ]
  }
}
```